# Rails 5 + postgresql table reference relation for multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, reference, ruby-on-rails-5, table-relationships

I have posts and users tables and relation as below

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "submitted_by_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
    ...
```

now I can get username for post as below

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

however in the posts table I also have submitted_by_id field which stores different user than the user_id

**So how can I get the username of submitted_by_id?** 
Do I need a separate relation for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add relationship in the Post model like below

```
belongs_to :submitted_by_user,
            class_name: 'User',
            primary_key: :id,
            foreign_key: 'submitted_by_id',
            optional: true
```

`optional: true` wont cause validation error for `submitted_by_user` presence

So in UI you can access like

```
<%= post.submitted_by_user.username %>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

Comment: Cool! it all makes sense now :D Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @praga2050 answer, but here's an opinionated alternative.

```
@posts.each {|post| User.find(post.submitted_by_id) }
```

if you don't want to make your relationships slightly more complex, just use the attribute you already have access to.

Comment: I love how simple this solution this! I often need such a solution in many places! Thank you!